# How to put files generated by CMAKE_AUTOMOC in specific folder

Tags: qt, cmake

I am doing a out of source build with CMake.
It is my current folder structure:

```
|_ProjectRoot
  |_build
  |_src
  |_inc
```

Since I am using Qt, my CMakeLists.txt file contains these line in order to generate required `ui_*.h` and `moc_*.h`:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
```

All `ui_*.h` and `moc_*.h` files are put in `ProjectRoot\build` by default.

Is there any chance I can specify the `moc_*.h` generated to be put under `ProjectRoot\moc` and `ui_*.h` to be put under `ProjectRoot\ui`.

Comment: What's the rationale? Usually you don't work with generated files, just the compiler?

Comment: @usr1234567 I concern about the deployment. If I need to distribute my source, people normally don't have the Meta Object Complier. I am thinking if I can compile the ui_files and moc_files first and distribute it.

Comment: Unless you distribute binaries, users will need Qt and CMake to compile your code anyway. So they'll have all they need to generate the files by themselves. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @usr1234567 I originally thought that I can generate all ui, meta object and resource files first. Then I could write a second CMake file to control the build process treating  them like normal .h and .cpp files. So I do a small test. It turns out that the build process succeeded at compile state but fail at linkage state. So does it mean Qt still have something to do at linkage state?

Comment: As far as I know, you still need the Qt libraries and headers for linking and compiling.

Comment: Qt library and header is small in size and not difficult to find so I can just provide the required one when deploy.

Comment: Exactly. CMake is small, too. And a compiler must be provided by the user. Why bother with auto-generated headers?

Comment: ASAIK moc of Qt cannot download independently. You must download whole package of qt which is 500 mb.

Answer (score 2):

CMake has no option to do that.

Comment: how about in 2018 ?